# WP & ACF: Runtime error in admin because of script queue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using WP with ACF, I've changed the order and files for loading JS in my theme and it seems this affects the queue of scripts in the admin as well, causing a runtime error.

The queue script in functions.php –

```
function enqueScripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', ( 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js' ), false, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'example', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/app.js', false, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'example' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'enqueScripts' );
```

Is there something I'm missing here that would prevent the queue from running in the admin? I only want this to load on the actual site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `init` since that'll prevent them from running in the admin views. Also, try making jquery a dependency for the 'example' script.

something like:

```
function enqueScripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', ( 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js' ), false, null, true );
    wp_register_script( 'example', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/app.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueScripts' );
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Using wp_enqueue_scripts as paremeter instead of init helped, thanks!